# Canceling Stripe subscription throws scheduling error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription

I recently increased the prices of my Stripe subscription plans on my Laravel SASS application. Now, when a user cancels their subscription, it throws the following error:

**"The subscription is managed by the subscription schedule `sub_sched_XXXXXXXXXX`, and updating any cancelation behavior directly is not allowed. Please update the schedule instead."**

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and have this in my composer.json file:
"laravel/cashier": "~7.0",

Basically, I get the subscription object and just call cancel(). E.g.:

```
$subscription->cancel();
```

This worked for years until I recently changed my prices. Is this a programming error on my part, or do I need to move my subscription plans off of schedules somehow? I'm really stumped here, because Googling has not turned up any useful results on this error.

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue. The recent price change moved the subscriptions onto a schedule. I had to release the subscription schedule using the API here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/release?lang=php